# Cannot copy from docker image using "COPY --from" command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, image, copy, jena, fuseki

There is a directory inside the stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 image that cannot be copied while other directories can be. I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.15-slim
COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /fuseki /fuseki
```

If I run `docker image build .` I  get the following response

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  435.9MB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.8.15-slim
 ---> f0fe0cb74bac
Step 2/2 : COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /fuseki /fuseki
COPY failed: stat fuseki: file does not exist
```

However, I looked into the image with `docker run -it stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0` and the directory does exist at the root level along with other directories which are copyable. E.g. following Dockerfile builds perfectly without any errors.

```
FROM python:3.8.15-slim
COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /jena-fuseki /jena-fuseki
```

I have tried many things like changing the working directory with `WORKDIR /` and also things like `COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /fuseki/. /fuseki`. However, none of them are working.
I have also not excluded anything with `.dockerignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuseki is a run time directory. It is created when the container is instantiated. So, it is not present at the build time. Hence the error.

This is proved by the timestamp of the files in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I don't only want to copy the /jena-fuseki folder but also the /fuseki folder. So I need 
COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /fuseki /fuseki
COPY --from=stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 /jena-fuseki/ /jena-fuseki
However the first one does not work

Comment: fuseki is a run time directory. It is created when the container is instantiated. So, it is not present at the build time. Hence the error.

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly. Please accept and close.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a multi-stage build, see here: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#name-your-build-stages

In your case, that would like something like:

```
FROM stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 AS jena
FROM python:3.8.15-slim
COPY --from=jena /jena-fuseki /jena-fuseki
```

Comment: With /jena-fuseki it works but with /fuseki it doesn't. That's my problem

Sending build context to Docker daemon  435.9MB
Step 1/3 : FROM stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0 AS jena
 ---> 1fa65fccaf09
Step 2/3 : FROM python:3.8.15-slim
 ---> f0fe0cb74bac
Step 3/3 : COPY --from=jena /fuseki /fuseki
COPY failed: stat fuseki: file does not exist